# Pulseaudio not starting

Tags: sound, pulseaudio

Well here's an embarrassing problem. PulseAudio doesn't seem to be working. I've been trying to load the sound applet for a week or so and I checked `ps aux | grep pulse` and found that there's no PA daemon running!

Sound is still working. I assume everything has fallen back to ALSA.

Furthermore I've tried to start PA from the command line. `pulseaudio -D` just errors out with nothing useful, just `E: main.c: Daemon startup failed.`

`pulseaudio` on its own raises a little more:

```
$ pulseaudio
E: main.c: Unknown command: !/usr/bin/pulseaudio -nF
E: main.c: Failed to initialise daemon.
```

I *can* start it as root with `--system` but nothing can connect to it. That's not the right way to run PA, so I'd rather fix it than bodge around it.

Comment: Also, pulseaudio -v, and you can add more "v"s for more info

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Well that was the weirdest thing. I opened up `/etc/pulse/default.pa` and noticed that the first line was:

```
!/usr/bin/pulseaudio -nF
```

That looks an awful lot like a `#!/bin/bash` style opening (I don't know the proper name for it, comments on a postcard) so I stuck a hash at the beginning like so:

```
#!/usr/bin/pulseaudio -nF
```

And it works!

No idea how that got broken. I don't think I've ever purposefully edited that file before.

Comment: Very interesting finding - good to know that such things happen. Here the line is commented out per default installation.

Comment: @Takkat it's not a comment - it's a pulseaudio script. That "comment" tells it to run with the `/usr/bin/pulseaudio` executable (just as #!/bin/bash tells the OS to run a script with `bash`)

Comment: Chat (marco and htorque) reliably tell me this like is called a [Interpreter directive](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interpreter_directive) (a shebang (`#!`) followed by a command).